# Dictionary as value - Overwriting all other previous values of NSMutableDictionary with the current value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I want to know if we can set value as dictionary for a dictionary.

I am trying to set value as dictionary, but when I set value for current key all the previous keys too get set with this value.

```
[self.mainDict setValue:self.buttonDict forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",device.deviceID]];
```

here is what I am getting for two iterations:

1st

```
main Dict {
    2 =     {
        1 =         (
            "object1",
            "object2"
        );
    };
}
```

2nd

```
main Dict {
    2 =     {
        1 =         (
            "object3",
            "object4"
        );
    };
    3 =     {
        1 =         (
            "object3",
            "object4"
        );
    };
}
```

Dictionary should be able to accept any kind of value right?, I suspect problem is something else

Comment: No, `NSDictionary` doesn't accept any value. _Keys_ must conform to the `NSCopying` protocol ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/setObject:forKey:))

Comment: Can you share your code with dictionary values?

Comment: @vijay: values in the output ?

Comment: @Masood values of dict you are setting.

Comment: Can you show more code. It looks like you are putting the same object in multiple dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge you are setting value of self.buttonDict for different keys.
That stores reference of self.buttonDict for that key.

When you change the self.buttonDict value, all pointer to that object gets updated. That's why changing a single object is changing your all Values.

Try making a separate object for self.buttonDict and then setValue with that object for your key in Dictionary.

Comment: You could also set the value to `[self.buttonDict copy]`.